# Calling SCCM from PowerShell or CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd, sccm

We have an application (really a platform) which we need to customise on a per-user role basis.  This involves asking some questions and then installing the application and then customising it before handing back to the user.

After the app has been installed, we need to update the application (but not the settings) from time to time as new versions are released.

Our IT people have said I should use a PowerShell/cmd script to do the initial install - because of its specificity.  I'd like to get SCCM to do the version updates but I've been told that if SCCM doesn't do the install, it doesn't know there's anything to update - fair enough!  So I was wondering how can I call SCCM from my PowerShell script to perform the initial install and then return control to my script for final customisation?

Answer (score 0):

On this site you can learn more about managing SCCM over PowerShell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sccm/overview?view=sccm-ps

But this won't be just a simple script, it will take a bit of time to create!

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but the (initial) install needs to take place on the user's machine (probably under a service account with privileges).  I guess I'll have to have some more discussions with IT.  (Perhaps "make them an offer they can't refuse..." :)"